# phonegap android: getting android.view.WindowLeaked exception

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to use localisation in my phonegap based android app .....

when i include the localisation plugin(jquery.localize.js) in my .html file and run it , its throwing an Application error "The connection to the server was unsuccessful.(file:///...../index.html)" and in the logcat showing an error android.view.WindowLeaked

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.localize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this would give you a window leak, but your missing some of your code. The `</body>` tag has no opener.

If this doesn't work, we would need more files to capture the error.